# Cannot see go online option in tfs

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I opened a solution in offline mode. But now I am trying to go online and connect to tfs but I cannot seem to see the "Go Online" Button under File-> Source Control.

I connected to TFS using Team-> Connect to Team Foundation Server option but I still don't see "Go Online" button in File-> Source Control.

Is there any other way to go online in TFS?

Version used : Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, connecting Team Foundation Server 2010.

Comment: Do you reckon seeing such an option earlier?

Comment: Yes, I used to see that option earlier.

Comment: Here's the solution that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13681808/1551006

Answer (score 35):

I found out that the "File > Source Control > Go Online" menu item doesn't appear when the "Source Control Explorer" window is active.

So you will have to open a different window and\or file.

In my case, when I opened a .cs file within a project of the open solution, the "Go Online" menu item was available once again.

Comment: URGH. I was searching for the button, the one that **used to be on the solution explorer**, then a google search made me find this answer. I won't comment this wonderfull UI idea (my comments would remember the Angry Videogame Nerd, so it's not the case). Just know that my co-workers are now left wondering why I have almost fall from the chair while laughing like a mad.... WHY, just tell me WHY.

Answer (score 6):

Try File > Source Control > Change Source Control, and then bind your solutions/projects.

Comment: If I use bind it is connecting to the TFS server but asking me to do a checkout of the project file. If I say yes, I have bunch of SLN and project files that checkout changed and are showing up in my pending changes.Is that normal?

Comment: If this is the first time you're binding the project, then this seems normal, as all of those files will need to go through an initial check-in.

Comment: This isn't the first time. The project is already in Source Control. I have checked into it earlier.

Comment: I still **think** this is fine.  If you're worried about the changes, right-click on each file and Compare > With Latest Versions, to see the changes that it's going to check-in.  If you don't want to check-in your changes, just right-click and Undo.

Comment: I too have same problem,While binding its asking to check out all projects/files and locking them. Its problem for my other colleagues.I I undo then it is removing the binding..got confused with TFS functionality

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem when i worked on my solution when i was disconnected from tfs.

I unloaded and loaded the project i worked offline and suddenly go online option showed.

I think doing that checks out the project so that unknown bindings are removed.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to delete the bindings of existing projects that failed to bind correctly.

Then close the binding dialog.

Now you can add each of the disconnected projects from your solution explorer.

This ranges somewhere between buggy and pathetic, but if you click around on sufficiently many seemingly unrelated menus, context menus, and dialogs, you may guess how to repair the TFS connection like this

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal, but another option is to close Visual Studio and open it again.

In my case whenever I get disconnected (we use TFS online) then after a drop in connectivity my VS thinks it is still offline, I cant convince it otherwise so when I restart VS it then forces it to check connectivity and then my solution is automatically back "online".