# Visual Studio 2012 - Solution Explorer - Checked Out By Another Person in Another Place

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

All of my coworkers can see in Visual Studio 2012 Solution Explorer when anybody else has code checked out.

The icon changes from Checked In to Checked Out By Another Person in Another Place.

But my Visual Studio does not update to change the icon when this takes place.  I went to another coworkers desk and had them check out a file and then I went back to mine and the icon did not update.  I checked out one of my files and it was correctly displayed on their screen.

Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2012?
Is there an option I can click in TFS, Visual Studio, or elsewhere where I can turn this option on?

It is quite annoying working with multiple developers and I do not know when somebody else has a file checked out.

I am currently running Visual Studio Professional 2012 - Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4

Comment: Removed C# tag, not sure how this is a question specifically with regards to C#.

Comment: @tnw Yep Sorry.  It was a misclick.

Comment: Make sure your solution is [online](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13681808/147211)

Comment: @kMoraz The solution is currently online and I can check in and out files by clicking on any item.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your coworker's Solution Explorer?  I didn't think that we ever decorated that with *other user's* pending changes.  Do they have any power tools or additional tools installed beyond Visual Studio?

Comment: @EdwardThomson We have the same exact version installed from MSDN.  I sent him a request to send me a screenshot.

Comment: Make sure TFS is the selected source control plugin (Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection)