# team server foundation 2010 is only working in offline mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

In my company, we are using Team Server Foundation 2010.

Last week when I was checking out some ssrs (sql server reporting services 2010) files, I obtained the correct files from TFS. I could see that the files were still connected to TFS.

However, I think there was a time last week where there was a message saying that I was working offline.

Now when I obtained the most current code from TFS, I do get the correct code. However I do not see that the code is connected to TFS any longer. Basically when using Source Control Explorer, I do not see that this code is linked to TFS

Thus I would like to know how to get my code back to accessed in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 0):

- Do you see the same problem with all files in TFS or only specific set of files?

  - Do you see this problem in only one workspace or in all workspaces on a single machine? Or does it affect all users?
  - What does it mean that files are not linked to TFS, can you post a screenshot?
  - TFS 2010 was quite weak story for offline and it worked only for solutions (as visible in Solution Explorer). Source Control Explorer always required connection to TFS

Answer (score 0):

I'm also confuse about “files are not linked to TFS”you describle ,can you post a screenshot.

Simply offline mode means TFS 2010 goes offline (disconnect the connectivity properly between your local machine and TFS 2010 server) while your solution is already open though VS 2010.If you checkout files while you are in offline mode, then TFS 2010 source controls system doesn’t record or track any changes you made. But when you reconnect TFS server, the server will get you changes in pengding changes, then you can check in manually.

To get your solution back online to TFS you can try this solution:right-click on the solution name right at the top of the Solution Explorer and select the Go Online option.
More detail: [How do I get my solution in Visual Studio back online in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681807/how-do-i-get-my-solution-in-visual-studio-back-online-in-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "go online" command to re-sync:

[Cannot see go online option in tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820128/cannot-see-go-online-option-in-tfs)

**Note: TFS 2010 is no longer supported and you should upgrade soonest**